# How can I have the inputted date of a text box checked for formatting before submission with regex?

Tags: php

I have an input text box that I have the end user fill in with the date when they perform an inspection. I want the date formatted like MM/DD/YYYY when it's stored in the database by the form's submission.

I have tried making a regex check using the preg_match function to check it but I have something not quite right with the else or else if commands. It is still allowing 04-05-2019 to be submitted and not stopping the submission.
any help would be appreciated!

```
//check inspection date format with regex
$date_check_regex = "/(0[1-9]|1[012])[- \/.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- 
\/.](19|20)\d\d/";

    // Validate inspection date
$cust_inspection_date = trim($_POST["cust_inspection_date"]);
if(empty($cust_inspection_date)){
    $cust_inspection_date_err = "Please enter the customers Inspection Date.";
} elseif(!filter_var($cust_inspecton_date, FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP, array("options"=>array("regexp"=>"/^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/")))){ 

    if(preg_match($date_check_regex, $cust_inspection_date)) {
    $cust_inspection_date = $cust_inspection_date;
} else {
    $cust_inspection_date_err = "Please enter a valid inspection date MM/DD/YYYY.";


}
}
```

and I have tried

```
// Processing form data when form is submitted
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){


//check inspection date regex check
$date_check_regex = "/(0[1-9]|1[012])[- \/.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- \/.](19|20)\d\d/";


    // Validate inspection date
    $cust_inspection_date = trim($_POST["cust_inspection_date"]);
    if(empty($cust_inspection_date)){
    $cust_inspection_date_err = "Please enter the customers Inspection Date.";

    if(!filter_var($cust_inspecton_date, FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP, array("options"=>array("regexp"=>"/^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/")))), 
    if(preg_match($date_check_regex, $cust_inspection_date)) {
    $cust_inspection_date = $cust_inspection_date;
} else {
    $cust_inspection_date_err = "Please enter a valid inspection date MM/DD/YYYY.";

    // $cust_inspection_date = $cust_inspection_date;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like its allowing the 04-05-2019 format because you are using the [- \/.], which allows the characters -, / , and . to be used.

If you require it to be only /, you would want to remove the . and -

```
(0[1-9]|1[012])[\/](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[\/](19|20)\d\d
```

Comment: Thank you I will give it a try 

Answer (score 1):

The problem with using a regex to parse dates is that it will allow illegal ones (e.g. 02/30/2019) through. It's usually better to use the built-in date parsing tools and verify that the date is valid. For example, to allow only dates in the form MM/DD/YYYY you could do something like this.

```
$cust_inspection_date = trim($_POST["cust_inspection_date"]);
$date = date_create_from_format('m/d/Y', $cust_inspection_date);
if (!$date || $date->format('m/d/Y') != $cust_inspection_date) {
    echo "$cust_inspection_date is invalid\n";
}
else {
    echo "$cust_inspection_date is valid\n";
}
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/LMkt8)